# creating mysqldump for postgres

Tags: mysql, postgresql

I am creating a mysql dump file to import in postgresql. I am using:

```
mysqldump -u username -p --compatible=postgresql databasename > outputfile.sql
```

Now, I have a problem the `INSERT` sentences, if there are a boolean column, the MySql dump write this value to the file as 0 or 1 (true or false), but when I import the dump with psql, this program require that the value for boolean fields be "true", or "false".

Any solution?

Comment: You will have more luck exporting the data to text files and then import them using the `copy` command.

Comment: ... or using an ETL tool like Talend Studio, Pentaho Kettle, CloverETL, etc to migrate data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

user3182456's answer is great. However, if you do not have access to `pg_cast` and you don't mind altering your MySQL database, then you can convert your `tinyint(1)` columns to `char(1)` first.  This will produce `'0'` and `'1'` in the dump and postgres understands those as booleans.

```
ALTER TABLE YourTable
MODIFY COLUMN YourTinyInt1Column CHAR(1);
```

Answer (score 2):

IF your problem is only from the booleans, you can change Postgresql (not a good solution, but a temp patch).

```
update pg_cast set castcontext='a' where casttarget = 'boolean'::regtype;
```

When you have finished:

```
update pg_cast set castcontext='e' where casttarget = 'boolean'::regtype;
```

Source: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/46140/have-postgresql-accept-1-and-0-as-true-and-false-for-boolean